# OpenGL - Any better way to draw lines in a parallel co-ordinate plot?

Tags: python, performance, opengl, lines

So I have written some OpenGL code in python to plot parallel co-ordinates, i.e. a plot such as this:

[image: Parallel Co-Ordinates OpenGL]

This currently works by splitting each line into n-1 (where n is the number of axes) smaller lines. Then each of the smaller lines is drawn with the same colour.

This is repeated for each complete line and the colour changed each time.

For simplicity in the comments lets define each complete line as the maximal line and the smaller lines which make up this maximal line as a line segment.

My question is whether there is a simpler way to draw these maximal lines? Perhaps a method whereby I don't need to split the maximal lines into line segments?

I am using VBO's in my current implementation and the time to draw 4million maximal lines (i.e 20million line segments as there are 6 axes) is approx. 108 seconds = 1 minute 48 seconds.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem here isn't drawling lines quickly, it's organising your data such that you only draw lines that are visible.  If you're drawing 20 million segments, the amount of overdraw is going to be enormous.  To my mind this is a partition problem, not a rendering speed issue.

Comment: Okay thats an aspect I haven't thought of until now, thanks for this. I will look into just drawing the visible lines and having some way to represent how much of the data each line segment represents.

Answer (score 1):

you can call `glDrawArrays` with mode `GL_LINE_STRIP` you don't need to split the maximal lines up

if you have a vbo fill with all maximal lines (each n points is a line) then you can just loop it (using C++ code)

```
for(int index = 0; index < lineCount*n; index +=n)
{
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, i, n);
}
```

or using `glMultiDrawArrays` to collect the to-be-drawn lines if you don't need all lines to be drawn

Comment: But it's not possible to do this from a VBO is it? As each maximal line requires a different colour? I'll have a look into it, it's just I think I researched this before and for some reason dismissed it as not possible.

Comment: Okay I understand that but lets say I have for example 1million unique lines, in which case the loop method will be very slow, so a VBO would be the way to go.

Comment: you could also add the color to each vertex but that would increase the amount of memory required immensely

Comment: If you include a colour component with your vertex, you can colour it without having to partition the set into different colours.  Though this will increase the size of the VBO you need by nVertices * size(float) * 4, of course.